# Simple scala code runs faster when I run it in an IDE, than from the terminal

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm quite new to scala and today while trying things out I wanted to test the performance of a very simple program :

```scala
import java.util.Scanner
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Tests {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val sc = new Scanner(System.in)

        println("Enter a positive number : ")
        val length = sc.nextInt

        val fp_t0 = System.currentTimeMillis
        val list1 = fpListFill(List(), length)
        val fp_t1 = System.currentTimeMillis

        println(s"[fp]: time to fill the list = ${fp_t1 - fp_t0} ms")
    }

    @tailrec
    def fpListFill(list: List[Int], count: Int): List[Int] = {
        if (count == 0) count :: list
        else fpListFill(count :: list, count - 1)
    }
}
```

It simply asks a positive number length to the user, and then creates a list of length 'length' in a recursive way.

I tested it two different ways, each time I would ask for a list with length = 1'000'000

First I compiled the code with scalac and ran with scala in the terminal, which gave me :

```
Enter a positive number : 
1000000
[fp]: time to fill the list = 795 ms
```

Then, I created a small project in IntelliJ IDEA in which I copied the above code. Running the program there, this is what I got :

```
Enter a positive number : 
1000000
[fp]: time to fill the list = 25 ms
```

As you can see, there's quite a big difference in terms of performance. Does someone know why ? Thx in advance.

Comment: If you execute from CLI with a new/fresh JVM each time (whereas the IDE may there one), that quite expected

Comment: Is the 25 ms from the first time you ran the code in IntelliJ?

Comment: @redeagle47 yes, i tested it several times in intelliJ and it was always around 25ms, same thing with around 800 ms in the terminal

Comment: did you use REPL or just run scala file? what about `-Xmx` param?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin I just ran the scala file, and I didn't use it in my example but I just tried it now. I've tried allocating up to 4GB of ram when running from the terminal but nothing changed

Comment: Try setting `-Xms` to the same value as `-Xmx`. Growing the JVM heap takes a substantial amount of time.